# How to change few key value pairs in ES6/ES7

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, ecmascript-2016

I have a lot of key value pairs in my object and I wanted to only change some of it. In my case below, i only wanted to change the `place`. The values to be submitted are all of them.

**Object**

```
values: { username: 'johndoe', password: 123, contact_no: '18323223', place: 'LA' }
```

**CODE**

```
onSubmit: (values) => {

  const formData = (values) => {
    return Object.assign({}, values, {
      place: 'Iowa',
    });
  };
  console.log(formData);

},
```

Comment: I don't understand what the problem is here. Doesn't the code you have work? What, specifically, is wrong with it?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you want to update a property in an object, you can use one of these two techniques:

```js
values = { username: 'johndoe', password: 123, contact_no: '18323223', place: 'LA' }
//method 1
values['place'] = 'Iowa';
console.log(values);
//method 2
values = {...values, place:'Iowa1'};
console.log(values);
```